# java - handle exception thrown from a library, stop from printing to stdout

Tags: java, exception, junit, console, stdout

I am using a java library that creates a thread and inside the thread has an uncaught Exception which goes to the stdout.

```
   try {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        Thread t = new Thread(...);
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do noting
    }
```

Does that make sense that this exception ends up being printed to stdout?
Because I get errors printed to the console when using the library in tests.

I tried redirecting the stdout with something like this:

```
PrintStream original = System.out;
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
                public void write(int b) {
                    //DO NOTHING
                }
            }));
```

It didn't work.. I think it has something to do with the exception being thrown from a thread which in ran inside the library.

How can I disable this from going to the console? or redirect it somewhere else?

**EDIT:**

So apparently the exceptions are printed because they go to System.err, I did something like this in the junit class

`static {
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            public void write(int b) {
            }
        }));
    }`

And it stopped the exceptions from printing to the console.

What I want is to disable **only** the System.err from a **specific package**.

Is it possible somehow? maybe using log4j2.xml?

Comment: are you sure its going to System.out and not System.err?  If you're catching an exception and literally doing nothing, then its not going to get written anywhere. You must have a line somewhere else where its getting written to the output.

Comment: Yeah apparently it does go to System.err. look at me edited answer please :)

Comment: I definitely think you should look into a logging library like log4j. That will allow you to control your logging, including specifying logging levels by package if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use log4j, slf4j and etc? You can config package based logs by level and write it where you want or ignore. You can define any config on it

Even ff you will override stdout and stderr from the beginning (On top of your main) it should stop them going to console

```
    PrintStream printStream4StoppingStdOutAndErr = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            //I am stopper for any out writer
        }
    });
    System.setOut(printStream4StoppingStdOutAndErr);
    System.setErr(printStream4StoppingStdOutAndErr);
```

Comment: Will it also stop it from going to the stdout/console?

Comment: You can configure to write stdout to file for example

Answer (score 0):

It is the behavior of JUnit to print exceptions that are not caught. The exception must be caught within the `Runnable.run()` that is passed to the thread or with [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))

Am I correct in thinking you are seeing this behavior when running this code via JUnit? Because this post has the junit tag but you have not mentioned it in your question.